# A keychain cannot be found to store "NETWORK."

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keychain

I just recently purchased a refurbished MacBook Air from Apple running Sierra.

For the most part it is functioning just how I would expect it to, except for the following: for certain networks (it appears to be limited to just wpa2 personal networks. wpa2 enterprise with RADIUS authentication connects automatically just fine) it will not remember the pass.

I leave the network, rejoin, and get prompted with the message:

> A keychain cannot be found to store "NETWORK."

It gives me an option to reset the keychain, which I would love to do (there are no custom CA/client certificates on here yet, just a stock certificate bank), but when it prompts me to put in my password, I can't type anything in the box.

I have tried the solution listed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/199762/220228k), but still get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A restart after applying system updates fixed this issue.

Answer (score -1):

There might be some system update which must be waiting, try restarting the Mac.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  The accepted answer already mentioned doing this (2 years ago).  Please [edit] your answer to provide more info as you risk receiving many downvotes for simply repeating another person's answer.